# Binding external URL in angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularjs app with a controller and a partial wired up..

In my controller I have a array of links..

```
$scope.links = ['http://www.example.com/1','http://www.example.com/2'];
```

In my partial, I have the following code..

```
 <div ng-repeat="link in links">
 <a href="{{link}}" target="_blank">Link</a>
 </div>
```

This does not seem to work.. I am running this via a NodeJS app locally..and so my URLs always end up as 
`http://dev-server.local:3000/"http://www.example.com"`

Can anyone please help me figure out how I can add a hyperlink from my controller directly into my partial template and make Angular not append the page URL..

Comment: did you use the `<base>` tag?

Comment: no i havent used the <base> tag

Comment: I am not sure of the usage of <base> tag.. can you please assist..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
href={{link}}
```

use

```
ng-href={{link}}
```

Comment: This is correct.. but there was a problem in my JSON parsing as well.. and that was also the reason it was failing..

Answer (score 6):

You have to explicitly trust extern URL:s. Look at the documentation for `$sce`.

In you controller, make sure you have a dependency to `$sce`, then in create a method that trust the external url.

```
$scope.trustUrl = function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
}
```

In your view you can reference this method and pass in the url with

```
<a ng-href="{{ trustUrl(item) }}">Click me!</a>
```