# Linking to an external url stored in MongoDB with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a basic CRUD application written using the MEAN stack. In this I have an 'issues' model of which a number of properties are stored, including an external url which a user inputs.

I am trying to display this url so when the user clicks on it they are redirected to an external page (i.e. new tab in the browser). I am using Angular for this part.

With my current code I am always opening a new tab with the following url (http://localhost:3000/www.google.com). Taking the Google homepage as an external url example stored in the database.

My current code looks something like this.

view-issue.client.view.html

```
<a ng-href="{{ trustUrl(issue.sourceUrl) }}">Click me!</a>
```

issues.client.controller.js

```
$scope.trustUrl = function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
};
```

I have also tried this solution already posted with the same result ([Linking to external URL with different domain from within an angularJS partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457962/linking-to-external-url-with-different-domain-from-within-an-angularjs-partial)).

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: WHat is the problem?

Comment: When the link is clicked my browser redirects to a url which looks something like: (http://localhost:3000/www.google.com). Instead of just being (www.google.com).

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the protocol in the url's. Without seeing the `//` browser will treat it as relative path. Need to check for `http[s]://`